# Create a view with Filter parameter

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm creating a view in hive which unions two tables and has a lot of data. Is there a way to pass a filter paramter to view in hive so that it is applied to the table as well. 
I have

```
CREATE VIEW abc 
AS
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM table_a
UNION 
SELECT * table_b) temp;
```

If I run something like `SELECT * FROM abc WHERE day='2018-10-22'`
It should return the union on the selected date only like

```
SELECT * FROM table _a WHERE day='2018-10-22' UNION
SELECT * FROM table _b WHERE day='2018-10-22'
```

How do I create a view to do this.

Comment: If you create a view with `UNION ALL` then query optimizer probably use predicate pushdown

Comment: I don't believe so.  Some databases support user-defined table-valued functions for this purpose.  Views don't have this capability.  You can cross your find and see if an external where clause (`where day = '2018-10-22'`) pushes the filtering into the view.  For Hive, I would be surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to add filter explicitly for optimization purposes. Query optimizer can push down the predicate. Take a look to this

```
CREATE TABLE `t5`(`a` string);
CREATE TABLE `t6`(`a` string);


CREATE VIEW v1 
AS
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM t5
UNION ALL
SELECT * from t6
) temp;
```

This is the explain of the query `select * from v1 where a = "b"`, as you can see there is 2 independent table scan and for each the predicate is applied. It would be really disappointing if  Hive at this point pull all the data and filter at the end :)

```
Explain
STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
  Stage-1 is a root stage
  Stage-0 depends on stages: Stage-1

STAGE PLANS:
  Stage: Stage-1
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            alias: t5
            filterExpr: (a = 'b') (type: boolean)
            Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 0 Basic stats: PARTIAL Column stats: NONE
            Filter Operator
              predicate: (a = 'b') (type: boolean)
              Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 0 Basic stats: PARTIAL Column stats: NONE
              Select Operator
                Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 0 Basic stats: PARTIAL Column stats: NONE
                Union
                  Statistics: Num rows: 2 Data size: 0 Basic stats: PARTIAL Column stats: NONE
                  Select Operator
                    expressions: 'b' (type: string)
                    outputColumnNames: _col0
                    Statistics: Num rows: 2 Data size: 0 Basic stats: PARTIAL Column stats: NONE
                    File Output Operator
                      compressed: false
                      Statistics: Num rows: 2 Data size: 0 Basic stats: PARTIAL Column stats: NONE
                      table:
                          input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
                          output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
                          serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
          TableScan
            alias: t6
            filterExpr: (a = 'b') (type: boolean)
            Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 0 Basic stats: PARTIAL Column stats: NONE
            Filter Operator
              predicate: (a = 'b') (type: boolean)
              Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 0 Basic stats: PARTIAL Column stats: NONE
              Select Operator
                Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 0 Basic stats: PARTIAL Column stats: NONE
                Union
                  Statistics: Num rows: 2 Data size: 0 Basic stats: PARTIAL Column stats: NONE
                  Select Operator
                    expressions: 'b' (type: string)
                    outputColumnNames: _col0
                    Statistics: Num rows: 2 Data size: 0 Basic stats: PARTIAL Column stats: NONE
                    File Output Operator
                      compressed: false
                      Statistics: Num rows: 2 Data size: 0 Basic stats: PARTIAL Column stats: NONE
                      table:
                          input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
                          output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
                          serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe

  Stage: Stage-0
    Fetch Operator
      limit: -1
      Processor Tree:
        ListSink
```